# How to set target attribute in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I have set a link to some text using `tinymce.execCommand("CreateLink", False, theLink)`. The problem is that I want to set `"Target=_blank"`.

How do I set a `Target` attribute after the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the correct html element in your tinymce editor. You can use this code to replace/set the target attribute of your link

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('a [href="'+theLink+'"]').attr('Target', '_blank');
```

Be aware that you might have the same link in the editor already. In this case all such links' target attributes become '_blank'.

Answer (score 9):

Are you trying to set the target attribute to _blank on all user-provided links in TinyMCE?  If so, set this property in your tinymce.init configuration:

```
extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target=_blank]'
```

This works for me on TinyMCE 4.0.2.

With this configuration, all links in the editor will have target set to _blank when the editor saves.  (Additionally, all attributes other than href and target will be removed since I excluded them in the configuration; add whatever valid attributes/constraints that you wish to allow.)

see: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:extended_valid_elements

If these are user-provided links, then you may also want to set rel=nofollow for all links they provide.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer giving the user the option, but making `target="_blank"` the default.

This appears to be correct for v4.4.3:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "link",
    default_link_target: "_blank"
});
```

You can also still specify the options:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "link",
    target_list: [
        {title: 'None', value: ''},
        {title: 'Same page', value: '_self'},
        {title: 'New page', value: '_blank'}
    ],
    default_link_target: "_blank"
});
```

It also appears support for `selected: true` has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

Making 'New page' an only option did work for me (see: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:target_list) in version 4.1.0

```
target_list: [ {title: 'New page', value: '_blank', selected: true} ]
```

Comment: While this does limit the selections in the UI, it didn't add `target="_blank"` on the created links when I tried it with 4.1.1.

Comment: Please try with "selected: true" added (even though undocumented)

Comment: I ended up forcing it with Ryan's approach but I retested with `selected: true` and that also works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "link",
    target_list: [
        // remove `none` and `_self` by commenting them like below
        // {title: 'None', value: ''},
        // {title: 'Same page', value: '_self'},
        {title: 'New page', value: '_blank'}
    ]
});
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:target_list